# Cannot GET/filename ERROR on Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I am trying to access another page from my node application, but this other (Branch.html)HTML Page doesn't load the files for me. All the files in index.html are working but when I switch to another page using the below code, it stops working:

```
app.get('/branch', function (req, res,html) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/reacted/branch.html'));
});
```

My folder structure is:
Interface-- APP.JS(that's where the below code is), then All my pages are in a folder called reacted:

```
app.use(express.static('reacted/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/reacted/index.html'));
});
```

Below is my code in Branch. html where I am getting error that my branches.json is not found.

```
 $.getJSON("/reacted/Branches.json", function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
    $('#users-dropdown').append(
    $('<option id="branchname" ></option>').val(item).html(item));
});

});
$('#users-dropdown').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: is the server responding with branches.json not found? can you also post what the route is saying exists for req.params when that route gets called?

Comment: It takes me to Branch.html, but withth in branch.html is the dropdown which is trying to call branches.json within the same folder, that's not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like your branch.html and your branch.json are in the same folder, you should try

```
$.getJSON("Branches.json", function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
    $('#users-dropdown').append(
    $('<option id="branchname" ></option>').val(item).html(item));
});
```

Comment: So what do I do in terms of changing forlder structure? how should it be?

Comment: It really depend on your preference, I like to put all my html in one place and all my js in another place, but it can stay as it is.

Except if this is causing problem, is it?

Comment: It looks like it needs to be in public folder, so Do I just paste all my code in public foldeR?

Comment: I would put all my html in public/html then all my .js in public/js, then I would modify my path accordingly, or you could put it all into public but it would be a mess if you have many files